# Php - name = function() callback var

Tags: php, function, callback

I use a function in a foreach loop. And I update some var inside this loop and I would like to pass it inside a function.
However, I don't understand and if it's possible to pass callback argument.
It seems to not working like that.

```
foreach($infos as $info) {
    $i = $info;
    $a = 'aaa';
    $b = 'bbb';
    $datas[$i] = function($a,$b) {
        $data['a'] = $a;
        $data['b'] = $b;
        return $data;
    };
}
return $datas;
```

How can I pass the var `$a`, `$b`?

Comment: $datas[$i] = function($a,$b,) syntax error. remove last comma.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to accomplish there. Why not just assign arrays right away? Should the result list `$datas` really contain the bound function, or better yet the `a`/`b` list? If you craft a list of closures, then you'll have to pass the $a/$b variables afterwards, to call each function, and then assign it back(?)

Comment: In fact $datas is in a add filter with call methode. I can only write it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you have to write it like that. Use a direct assignment instead

```
$datas = array();
foreach($infos as $info) {
    $a = 'aaa';
    $b = 'bbb';
    $datas[$info] = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I can't assign it like this, I must use a callback filter to assign a funtion for _call() method function().

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you wan't to accomplish here but anonymous function can inherit variables from the parent scope with "use". So try:

```
foreach($infos as $info) {
    $i = $info;
    $a = 'aaa';
    $b = 'bbb';
    $datas[$i] = function() use ($a, $b) {
        $data['a'] = $a;
        $data['b'] = $b;
        return $data;
    };
}
return $datas;
```

Answer (score 0):

See here - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-195.
Must be something like this:

```
$datas[$i] = function() use($a,$b) {
   $data['a'] = $a;
   $data['b'] = $b;
   return $data;
};
```